# Convert a large RasterStack to Array in R

Tags: r, array, rasterstack

I am trying to transform a large RasterStack to an array in order to compute some extraction. The classical approach raster::as.array() is not working since the files are very large and it's taking too long.

I've tried another approach, by first extracting the values from the RasterStack and then building an array, however, it's not working. Probably is related to the way I am filling the arrays, but I couldn't understand very well.

Here is an example:

```
library(raster)

### Data
ext <- extent(0,100,0,100)    
r1 <- raster(nrows=100, ncols=100,ext)    
r1[] <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 6, by = 1), size = 10000, replace = TRUE)    
r2 <- raster(nrows=100, ncols=100,ext)    
r2[] <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 6, by = 1), size = 10000, replace = TRUE)    
r3 <- raster(nrows=100, ncols=100,ext)    
r3[] <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 6, by = 1), size = 10000, replace = TRUE)

s <- stack(r1,r2,r3)

### My approach
r_val <- getValues(s)

r_arr <- array(r_val, dim = c(100, 100, 3))

### Classic approach
r_arr2 <- raster::as.array(s)

### Check if equal
matequal <- function(x, y)
  is.matrix(x) && is.matrix(y) && dim(x) == dim(y) && all(x == y)

matequal(r_arr, r_arr2)   

[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following sessionInfo()

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] raster_3.4-5 sp_1.4-5    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.3   Rcpp_1.0.6       codetools_0.2-18 grid_4.0.3      
[5] lattice_0.20-41
```

I was able to simply do;

**Create some random example data**

```
library(raster)
( r <- do.call(raster::stack, replicate(4, 
             raster::raster(matrix(runif(25), 5, 5)))) )
```

**Coerce to array and check first raster element against first array/matrix element**

```
( ra <- as.array(r) )
  as.matrix(r[[1]])
  ra[,,1]
```

**Look at equality of all rasters against corresponding matrices in array**

```
for(i in 1:nlayers(r)) {
  print(any(ra[,,i] == as.matrix(r[[i]])))
}
```

So, nothing seems to have changed. I tested this on your example data as well and got the same results, with nothing amiss.